# MongoDB Norm query nested objects

Tags: c#, mongodb, norm

Does anyone have a sample of how to query for nested/inner objects in MongoDB using NORM (C#)? For example, if a typical document in a collection looks like Order/OrderItems, how can I look up a specific OrderItem by OrderItem.Quantity > 10.

Answer (score 0):

Typing this from memory, so sorry if it's wildly wrong:

```
using ( var session = new MongoSession<Order>( DbName ) )
{
    var orders = session.Queryable
                .Where( o => o.OrderItems.Any( oi => oi.Quantity > 10 ) )
                .ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create extra field 'size', that you increment when add new items, and query on it.